# Set Radar(spider) chart version 2.x (2.4.0) steps(interval) in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have searched to set the steps value but I am not get the answer. If any one know kindly share your thought for steps:

**Working As following way:**

```
0
0.5
1
1.5
.
.
5
```

**Expected:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Script:**

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
       beginAtZero: true,
       max: 5,
       steps : 1//Not working
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very sorry, Small thing finally I got the answer:

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
       beginAtZero: true,
       max: 5,
       stepSize: 1 //working Now
    }
}
```